# uninstalling Visual studio 2017 enterprise and installing VS 2017 community

Tags: visual-studio, uninstallation, visual-studio-2017

I would like uninstall visual studio 2017 enterprise from my window surface pro. after that i would like to install visual studio 2017 community. just wanted to ask the following,

- is it going to be just uninstall the current version of vs from programmes and installing the new version.
- is there any potential issue i need to be aware off?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Please, read the documentation:

- [Microsoft Docs | Install Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio)
- [Microsoft Docs | Uninstall Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio)

> is it going to be just uninstall the current version of vs from
>   programmes and installing the new version.

Yes, uninstall Enterprise Edition and install Community. Or do it vice-verse.

BTW, you should run *Visual Studio Installer*, not *Programs and Features* to manage your VS2017 installations.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for after installing Visual Studio Enterprise and then later installing Visual Studio Professional. If I were to do it again, I would uninstall whichever version of Visual Studios you have, and then install the desired version. Why? When I had both installed, it created many duplicate files that were unnecessary.

Comment: The hit to use the Visual Studio Installer rather than Programs and Features is exactly what I needed to know.  Thank you.

Comment: Enterprise somehow installed itself when installing Community (or maybe I clicked something who knows), but the installer, even for 15.5.2 wouldn't page down for some reason on a 768p screen. So the items on the `More` button were hard to see, in fact the selector for repair & uninstall covered both items, not separately. The Installer screen underlapped the taskbar, making the uninstall option not readily visible. Nice to know Enterprise could be uninstalled, having it around was a bit awkward as its right click context identifier was identical to the Community item.

Comment: Has anyone tested if the uninstall removes everything installed with it originally? I've never had a real clean uninstall in the past so I'm postponing moving from 2017 to 2019. As there was always a SQL Server or some other dependency that's left behind when I tried it before with other versions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you **do not** need to uninstall the VS enterprise 2017 in your scenario. For VS 2017, we can keep different versions on the same computer. Please check this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#whats-new-in-visual-studio-2017 and find the following information:

Installation Nickname

**Visual Studio Enterprise and Community (among other products) can now be installed side-by-side on the same computer.** To make identifying these installations simpler, you can specify a short name or "nickname". For example, if you were to install Visual Studio Enterprise, and then install Community, both would appear the same on the start menu. You can give the second one a nickname like "community", and the start menu items will appear with names such as "Visual Studio 2017 (community)" and "Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2017 (community)".

Comment: Just something to be wary of. VS 2017 and VS 2019 currently are sharing config (real time), if you change something in one, it affects immediately the other. So having VS 2017 with Resharper and trying to use Vs 2019 vanilla just to get to know it turns out to be a very difficult task. As one messes the shortcuts of the other.